# Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices: Failed to start node process

Tags: asp.net-core

I'm using `Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices 1.1.1` in my ASP.Net Core application. Everything has been working fine, but now I'm on a new computer and I get the following error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException:
Failed to start Node process. To resolve this:.

[1] Ensure that Node.js is installed and can be found in one of the PATH directories.
    Current PATH enviroment variable is: ....
    Make sure the Node executable is in one of those directories, or update your PATH.

[2] See the InnerException for further details of the cause.
```

I have removed the path variables from this question, but the directory where Node is installed is listed in there.

`node -v` in a terminal gives me `v6.11.0` so it is added to the path.

Nothing in the code has changed since it last worked, only my computer. Does anyone know what could be wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After debugging I found out that it was due to a missing folder.

This is how `NodeServices` was configured in `Startup.cs`:

```
services.AddNodeServices(options =>
{
    options.ProjectPath = "Path\That\Doesnt\Exist";
});
```

Once I added that path, everything runs okay.

Comment: what did you put in the location ?? Node.js path or project path

Comment: @SanJaisy The path to where the `package.json` and the js files are

Comment: Your mentioned value of `options.ProjectPath` is very useful, I got the answer from that

Comment: In my case I was debugging using docker, and the dockerfile did not have a section to setup node.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code snippet to get a client project

```
 services.AddNodeServices(options =>{
              options.ProjectPath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "ClientApp");  });
```

Comment: Would this not reduce to "ClientApp/" since Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() is the directory containing the assembly?

Comment: It will give the current directory of ClientApp and but the above problem is like the PATH environment variable not solved by it. If you have path issue you should set path first

Comment: Makes more sense now. Since ProjectPath is not set.

Comment: I have node v8.11.3 installed. verified by node -v. I have the correct PATH set 100%. I am debugging in vs 2017. I have tried adding the above line and I'm still receiving this error. 'AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (Failed to start Node process.'

Answer (score 0):

For me the error was caused after upgrading my website from Net Core 2.2 to 3.0.

The upgrade altered my `web.config` file, in particular this part:

```
<handlers>
    <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
</handlers>

<aspNetCore processPath=".\MyWebsite.exe" arguments="" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" />
```

became this:

```
<handlers>
    <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
</handlers>

<aspNetCore processPath="%LAUNCHER_PATH%" arguments="%LAUNCHER_ARGS%" stdoutLogEnabled="false" hostingModel="inprocess">
    <environmentVariables>
      <environmentVariable name="COMPLUS_ForceENC" value="1" />
      <environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" value="Development" />
    </environmentVariables>
</aspNetCore>
```

I fixed the issue by setting `processPath` and `arguments` back their previous values, and completely removed the `<environmentVariables>` section.