# AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (One or more errors occurred. (Failed to start 'npm'. To resolve this:

Tags: node.js, visual-studio, docker, npm, asp.net-core

Visual studio on mac with docker is having lots of error getting frustration . I, have a project on asp.net core 2.1 with angular 6 on docker image. When The project is successfully builded but not able to run below is the details :

**An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (One or more errors occurred. (Failed to start 'npm'. To resolve this:.
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dcump.png) Ensure that 'npm' is installed and can be found in one of the PATH directories.
Current PATH enviroment variable is: /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
Make sure the executable is in one of those directories, or update your PATH.
[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bgu7R.png) See the InnerException for further details of the cause.))
System.Threading.Tasks.Task.GetResultCore(bool waitCompletionNotification)
InvalidOperationException: Failed to start 'npm'. To resolve this:.
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dcump.png) Ensure that 'npm' is installed and can be found in one of the PATH directories.
Current PATH enviroment variable is: /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
Make sure the executable is in one of those directories, or update your PATH.
[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bgu7R.png) See the InnerException for further details of the cause.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices.Npm.NpmScriptRunner.LaunchNodeProcess(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)**

[image: info for details]

[image: added more image]

```
services.AddNodeServices(options =>
            {
                options.ProjectPath = "/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Commands:/Applications/Visual Studio.app/Contents/Resources:/Applications/Visual Studio.app/Contents/MacOS:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/share/dotnet:/usr/local/bin/";
            });
```

Here is the docker file info

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-sdk AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-sdk AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY MeroRentalDev.sln ./
COPY WebApp/WebApp.csproj WebApp/
RUN dotnet restore -nowarn:msb3202,nu1503
COPY . .
WORKDIR /src/WebApp
RUN dotnet build -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "WebApp.dll"]
```

Tried many solution for the link but not able to solve 
[System Aggregation Exception : Failed to start Node Process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50505974/system-aggregation-exception-failed-to-start-node-process)

[Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices: Failed to start node process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44635280/microsoft-aspnetcore-nodeservices-failed-to-start-node-process)

https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices/issues/227

https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices/issues/707

Answer (score 7):

Finally Solve the issue. This issue was due to node.js is not install on asp.net core 2.1 docker image.

So install the node js in docker container

```
# Setup NodeJs
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y wget && \
    apt-get install -y gnupg2 && \
    wget -qO- https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | bash - && \
    apt-get install -y build-essential nodejs
# End setup
```

check the version of node before you modify and change the node version value. In my case I,have 8.11.3 so **setup_8.x**

Full docker file

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-sdk AS base

    # Setup NodeJs
    RUN apt-get update && \
        apt-get install -y wget && \
        apt-get install -y gnupg2 && \
        wget -qO- https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | bash - && \
        apt-get install -y build-essential nodejs
    # End setup
    WORKDIR /app
    EXPOSE 80

    FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-sdk AS build
    WORKDIR /src
    COPY MeroRentalDev.sln ./
    COPY WebApp/WebApp.csproj WebApp/
    RUN dotnet restore -nowarn:msb3202,nu1503
    COPY . .
    WORKDIR /src/WebApp
    RUN dotnet build -c Release -o /app

    FROM build AS publish
    RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o /app

    FROM base AS final
    WORKDIR /app
    COPY --from=publish /app .
    ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "WebApp.dll"]
```

source - https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/298
[Configuring Dockerfile for an ASP.NET Core 2.1 Angular Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50859980/configuring-dockerfile-for-an-asp-net-core-2-1-angular-project)

Answer (score 2):

**I'm going to post another potential cause of the issue** (albeit one that *is* somewhat related to the existing answer) in the interest of helping those searching the error message.

---

In addition to the current answer(s), this error can also arise if you're (mistakenly or otherwise) running with the `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` env var set to 'Development' in non-Dev environments.

---

For instance, if you have code such as below in `Startup.cs`, and you've (deliberately) not installed `npm` in the environment in question, you'll see the aforementioned error message when your Dotnet app tries to run `npm start`.

```
if (env.IsDevelopment())
{
    spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start");
}
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-3.1