# Configuring Dockerfile for an ASP.NET Core 2.1 Angular Project

Tags: angular, docker, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, docker-for-windows

I'm a complete newbie on Docker and currently trying to create an ASP.NET Core 2.1 with Angular project. I'm using a Linux Container on Docker for Windows and my IDE is VS2017 community edition.

Currently, I'm receiving this error:

> [1] Ensure that 'npm' is installed and can be found in one of the PATH directories.
>   Current PATH enviroment variable is: /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
>   Make sure the executable is in one of those directories, or update your PATH.

I believe I need to install Node.js in my Docker instance or whatever you call that, and it should be through Dockerfile. Please point out my mistakes in my assumption. And how to ensure that the dependencies will be installed regardless on what kind of container I'm using? I'm expecting that my future projects will be installed on different platforms.

Comment: Exactly which image are you using?

Comment: @IgnacioMillán how to check that? Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In the microsoft/dotnet:2.1-aspnetcore-runtime container image npm/nodejs is not installed. To install this in the container update the docker file

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-aspnetcore-runtime AS base

# Setup NodeJs
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y wget && \
    apt-get install -y gnupg2 && \
    wget -qO- https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_6.x | bash - && \
    apt-get install -y build-essential nodejs
# End setup

WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
```

Only Angular CLI live reload is not working.

Comment: Saw this before on Github but I have no idea where should I put this code. Thanks for pointing out where I should place this. Though I changed setup_6.x to setup_10.x because what I installed on my machine is Node.js v10. It is working now. Thanks again!

Comment: You might also need to add the code to install node on the second container, ie. after:
`FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-sdk AS build`

If you get messages similar to 'Module build failed : error : Missing binding /src/myapp.UI/ClientApp/node_modules/node-sass/..' try adding the following:
`FROM build AS publish
WORKDIR /src/myapp.UI/ClientApp
RUN npm rebuild node-sass --force
WORKDIR /src/myapp.UI
RUN dotnet publish myapp.UI.csproj -c Release -o /app`

Comment: @Marcel is there a way to get live reloading working?

Answer (score 0):

Because of publish happens on based microsoft/dotnet:2.1-sdk image. So, this base image contains only dotnet sdk but not npm installed this base image.
There are 2 steps for solving this problem:

1) Adding installation nodejs to existing dotnet:2.1-sdk as written in answer by @Marcel.

or

2) You may add additional step to Dockerfile for building frontend side based on [NODE](https://hub.docker.com/_/node/) image and build your Angular. After success build you will get generated frontend files and will copy them to runtime image on final stage. So you will not add any installation to dotnet sdk with this option and with one Dockerfile with multiple stages you will build backend side seperately and frontend site seperately.

If you would like to make it as second option, please follow below link for building frontend on Dockerfile seperately with ASP.NET Core on same docker file:

[Dockerize ASP.NET Core Angular application (Solving error: The command “npm install” exited with code 127.)](http://alakbarv.azurewebsites.net/2019/01/11/dockerize-asp-net-core-angular-application-solving-error-the-command-npm-install-exited-with-code-127)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of install NPM and Node.js to the base image, you can also choose a base image that has the frameworks **preinstalled**. You can use my dotnet-angular image which is publicly available on [hub.docker.com](https://hub.docker.com/r/mjibrandl/dotnetcore-angular). Just replace

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2-sdk AS build
```

with

```
FROM mjibrandl/dotnetcore-angular:latest AS build
```

Check also my article: [Setup Azure DevOps YAML pipeline to publish a .NET Core Angular 7 docker container to Azure Container Registry](https://about-azure.com/2019/03/08/setup-azure-devops-yaml-pipeline-to-publish-a-net-core-angular-7-docker-container-to-azure-container-registry/)